# Azure using powershell how to get instance count

Tags: powershell, azure

Using powershell how do i get instance count. I have tried this sample code

```
get-azuredeployment -slot Production | where {$_.RoleInstanceList -ne $null} | ft servicename, @{expression={$_.roleinstancelist.count}; label='Instance Count'; alignment='left'}
```

but this requires me to enter service name. How do i get just the service name to pass in there and get a complete list.

I tried get-AzureVM but it seems to repeat service name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `Get-AzureService` cmdlet.

```
Get-AzureService | Get-AzureDeployment -Slot Production | where {$_.RoleInstanceList -ne $null} | ft servicename, @{expression={$_.roleinstancelist.count}; label='Instance Count'; alignment='left'}
```